# Alternative to xamarin method GetOrCreateRenderer()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.droid

Trying to use method **GetOrCreateRenderer()** but visual studios says it doesn't contains a definition for that. Maybe it was removed on newer versions or I'm not using the right namespace?

```
loadingIndicatorPage.Parent = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;
loadingIndicatorPage.Layout(new Rectangle(0, 0,Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Width,
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Height));
var renderer = loadingIndicatorPage.GetOrCreateRenderer(); //not recognized
_nativeView = renderer.View;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetOrCreateRenderer() is deprecated, now use:

`Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view,context);`

Comment: I had trouble finding this due to Xamarin.Essentials also having a Platform class, so the fully qualified is `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRendererWithContext`